# Optimized way to list and delete files

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find

I need to list and delete .php, .xml files. For this I am using `find` command.

**To list :**
`find . -type f -name \*.php -print0`

**To delete :**
`find . -type f -name \*.php -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r`

As I run `find` two times. Is it possible to store result of first command and then reuse in second ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | tee list | tr \\0 \\n
xargs -r0 rm -f < list
```

That's assuming you want to see the list before deciding to delete them. If not, you can simply do:

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -print -delete
```

(note that `-print0`, `-delete`, `-r`, `-0` are not standard but supported by the GNU implementation)

Also beware that while `find -delete` is relatively safe, in the first solution, someone could rename directories to symlinks to some sensitive areas between the time you run the `find` and `xargs` command and make you delete files that you didn't intend to. Running `find` twice, the second time with `-delete` would avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need `.php` and `.xml` files the `find` command should look like:

```
find . \( -name '*.php' -o -name '*.xml' \) -type f -print -exec rm {} +
```

The `+` instrucs `find` to use `rm` only once per chunk of files. If we had used `\;` we'd have run one `rm` command for each file.

Comment: Ahh...cool way ..actually I have a pretty long script with many files like xml, php, SVN folders etc. For brevity I had mentioned only couple of them.

Comment: Nice fast and short!

Comment: Note that `-exec rm {} +` is a speed up over `-exec rm {} \;`, but not over `-print0 | xargs -r0 rm` nor `-delete` but is less safe than `-execdir rm {} \;` or `-delete` because of the race condition mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Well, since you are invoking `tee` `tr` and `xargs` meaning that three different external programs are spawned, the command will not be fast as you think. Also the OP asks for the `.xml` files to be included which is not covered in your answer. I'm very curious to see a benchmark on the commands above.

Comment: I would recommend to first use "echo rm" instead of directly "rm" and only take out the "echo" once one it is sure that it's safe enough ^^. I prefer Stephane's answer for the safety side.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are meaning by `echo rm`. Mind to explain how the first answer makes it more safe?.

Comment: Oliver means run it once with `... -exec echo rm {} +` and if it looks like it's going to do what you want/expect, run it for real with `... -exec rm {} +`.  i.e. a dry-run first.  can do the same thing with xargs easily enough, too, with `xargs echo rm` and `xargs rm`.